# Custom attribute in aurelia no working?

Tags: aurelia

I am learning how Aurelia works and I am trying to get a simple custom attribute working. All it will do is change the color of a div text depending on some value changing.

I have a div which has:

```
    high.bind="changeColor"
```

and in my attribute I have :

```
import {inject, customAttribute} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customAttribute('high')
@inject(Element)
export class High {
    constructor(element) {
       this.element = element;
   }

   valueChanged(newValue){
   console.log(newValue);
   if (newValue) {
     this.element.classList.remove('highlight-yellow');
   } else {
     this.element.classList.add('highlight-blue');
  }
}
```

In my view model I have :

```
import {high} from './highlightattribute'


export class Welcome{
  heading = 'Welcome to the Aurelia Navigation App!';
  firstName = 'John';
  lastName = 'Doe';

 get fullName(){
   return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
 }

 get changeColor(){
  if (this.firstName == 'John'){
    return false;  
  }
  return true;
 }  
 welcome(){
   alert(`Welcome, ${this.fullName}!`);
 }
}
```

When I change the firstname I do not see the valueChanged event being triggered in the high custom attribute class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you are importing the high code in to your viewmodel rather than your view. Remove this line in your ViewModel:

```
import {high} from './highlightattribute'
```

Then and add this line to your View:

```
<require from="./highlightattribute"></require>
```

Next, in the `highlightattribute.js` file you are removing `highlight-yellow` and adding `highlight-blue`, so you will probably want to add and remove the same class. I did also notice that there is a missing parenthesis in your `highlightattribute.js` file you posted, but that was probably just missed while copying the code.

Let me know if this helps solve the problems. I have pushed a sample with your code to here: https://github.com/AshleyGrant/skeleton-navigation/tree/so-answer-20150416-01/src

Comment: Thank you so much Ashley. My first look at Aurelia so I really appreciate the help. No more angularjs for me :).