# CustomAttribute looking for html

Tags: aurelia, custom-attribute

I am trying to build a custom attribute in Aurelia based on `CustomAttribute` convention. However, when I am trying to use it in view, using `<import from='./shared/tr'></import>`,aurelia tries to look for `tr.html` in the same path.

Exactly what I am missing here?

**EDIT:**
The `tr.js` looks like below:

```
import aur = require("aurelia-framework");

export class TrCustomAttribute {

    public element;
    static inject = [Element];

    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;        
    }

    bind() {
       console.log(this.element);
    }

    valueChanged(newValue) {
        if (newValue) {
            console.log(newValue);
        }
        console.log(this.element);

    }
}
```

And I am trying to use the attribute as below:

```
<import from='./shared/tr'></import>
<button class="btn btn-primary" tr="something"> Something </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for `<require from='./shared/tr'></require>` rather than import. I made the same mistake a few times and still miss it :)

Comment: I tried that, but in that case, the tr.js file is not even being requested from browser.

Comment: What does tr.js look like? Is it anything like [custom attribute in aurelia not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680191/custom-attribute-in-aurelia-no-working)

Comment: Please check the Edit I have made in the question. Thank You.